# Google Calendar API returning "Daily Limit"

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-cloud-console

I'm using the nodejs googleapis module to authenticate the google calendar API. I've managed to get an access token. My code is below:

```
var tok = { 
  access_token: 'ya29.XXXXX-XXXXXXX',
  refresh_token: '1/XXXXXXXXXXX',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expiry_date: 1569089181800 
}
const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', tok});
calendar.events.list({
  calendarId: 'primary',
  timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
  maxResults: 10000,
  singleEvents: true,
  orderBy: 'startTime',
}, (err, res) => {

});
```

Each time I run this command I get the following error: `The API returned an error: Error: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.`

Can't figure out why this is the case (seeing as it was working before and I've only used a handful of requests). I've enabled billing and enabled/disabled/re-enabled the calendar API in the Google Cloud console.

Comment: Where did you get the access and refresh tokens from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the token is expired since the epoch value corresponds to

```
Sep 21 2019 17:30:00 UTC/GMT
```

I think you need a fresh token

Comment: hmm i see but I just went through the authentication flow and granted access, why would this be the case?

Comment: Perhaps some internal validation oon the API side , does changing the value help.

Comment: Not sure I follow entirely, how would you suggest I update this? Thanks

Comment: I think you may want to put in a step I. Your code which retrieves a fresh access token and refresh token from the identity provider once the old token expires.